# how do i install quadprog on mac os

Tags: python, quadprog

I'm having some difficulty installing `quadprog` on macOS under Python 3.6.
I've tried numerous solutions but nothing seems to be working.

What I need to install is `trajectory_planning_helpers` and it needs `quadprog`.
This is the error that I'm getting when I enter the command `pip3 install quadprog`:

```
3 warnings generated.
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Iquadprog -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c quadprog/aind.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/quadprog/aind.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Iquadprog -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c quadprog/solve.QP.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/quadprog/solve.QP.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Iquadprog -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c quadprog/util.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/quadprog/util.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Iquadprog -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c quadprog/dpofa.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/quadprog/dpofa.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Iquadprog -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c quadprog/daxpy.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/quadprog/daxpy.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Iquadprog -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c quadprog/ddot.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/quadprog/ddot.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Iquadprog -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c quadprog/dscal.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/quadprog/dscal.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Iquadprog -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c quadprog/f2c_lite.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/quadprog/f2c_lite.o
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6
    /usr/bin/clang++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/quadprog/quadprog.o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/quadprog/aind.o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/quadprog/solve.QP.o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/quadprog/util.o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/quadprog/dpofa.o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/quadprog/daxpy.o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/quadprog/ddot.o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/quadprog/dscal.o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/quadprog/f2c_lite.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/quadprog.cpython-36m-darwin.so
    clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
    clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
    ld: library not found for -lstdc++
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang++' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/r3/42nmx6bs2gbgxj3gm1hcl6_00000gn/T/pip-install-fvpe_m9v/quadprog/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/r3/42nmx6bs2gbgxj3gm1hcl6_00000gn/T/pip-install-fvpe_m9v/quadprog/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/r3/42nmx6bs2gbgxj3gm1hcl6_00000gn/T/pip-record-0k3qjcbz/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output
```

Comment: See the two clang warnings followed by library not found for -lstdc++.  It seems this library may be deprecated and is not found on your Mac.  If I knew anything about this software or its build process I would provide an answer.  But this is the specific reason it is not building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with Python 3.7 on my macbook and it got installed properly.

Based on the error message provided by you, I suspect that the problem could be either with the Python version (3.6) or with lstdc++ version (10.6)

Can you try upgrading Python to version 3.7 and then install quadprog?

**Here is the installation that worked for Python 3.7**

```
$ pip3 install quadprog
```

Collecting quadprog
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/.../quadprog-0.1.7.tar.gz

Collecting Cython (from quadprog)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/.../Cython-0.29.14-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (2.9MB)

....

Installing collected packages: Cython, quadprog

Running setup.py install for quadprog ... done

Successfully installed Cython-0.29.14 quadprog-0.1.7

Comment: Cython is ok
its just the quadprog tha has a problem

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement quadprog-0.1.7.tar.gz.cpgz (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for quadprog-0.1.7.tar.gz.cpgz

Comment: this is what i get for quadprog